# react string replace {image0} with actual image ramda?

Tags: react-native

I can feel the following is definitely not the optimal nor the cleanest way to do this. But I'm not quite sure how to refactor this.

```
const formatBtnText = (txt, color, image) => {
  const regex = /{image[\d]*}/g;
  const matches = [...txt.matchAll(regex)];

  if (!matches) {
    return <Text style={[styles.buttonText, { color }]}>{txt}</Text>;
  }

  const strings = txt.split(regex);
  let strIndex = 0;
  let matchIndex = 0;

  const res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < strings.length + matches.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      // every even is string
      if (strings[strIndex] !== '') {
        res.push(
          <Text key={`${strIndex}_string`} style={[styles.buttonText, { color }]}>
            {strings[strIndex]}
          </Text>
        );
      }
      strIndex++;
    } else {
      // every other is match
      res.push(
        <Image
          key={`${matchIndex}_image`}
          source={{ uri: image.uri }}
          style={[styles.buttonImage, { width: (12 * image.width) / image.height }]}
        />
      );
      matchIndex++;
    }
  }
  return res;
};
```